# How can i parse attribute name as parameter in Python

Tags: python, selenium, parameter-passing

I am trying to parse an Object Attribute Name as a parameter in my method, but i get

```
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'selector'
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def exist(browser, selector, id):
    try:
        browser.find_element(browser, By.selector, id)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

And here is my call:

```
if exist(browser, 'ID', '#errorTitleText'):
    print 'Element Exists!'
```

What am I doing wrong? Without the 'selector' parameter it is working.

Answer (score 1):

It is `CSS_SELECTOR`:

```
 browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)
```

You can also simply use:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
```

`find_element` takes **two parameters,** *`by`* and *`value`.* The default is *by.ID* so if you want to search using an `id` the pass it in.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def exist(browser, by_selector, value):
    try:
        browser.find_element(by_selector, value)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

Then pass in whatever you want:

```
exist(browser,By.ID, "id_value")
```

Comment: I understand and I fixed it but it still gives me the same error: "AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'selector'" ...

Comment: @PitoAxiu, what are you trying to locate with, using an id, css selector or what exactly?

Comment: I am trying to make a method which checks if element exist based on any locator i give... when i was testing it i was checking for element with ID errorTitleText

Comment: Why are you trying to use a selector is you want to search by id?

Comment: As I said I am trying to make a method to check if elements for ANY GIVEN LOCATOR ...

Comment: Anyway i thank you since i fixed my problem i dont know exactly how but know its working :)

Comment: @PitoAxiu, first off you passed three args to a method that took two, you need to pass in the selector you want to use `By.ID, By.CLASS_NAME` etc.. and the second arg is the value

Comment: Thanks now i saw what i did and i fixed it and posted below just before you updated ... thank you a lot

Comment: @PitoAxiu, your version is still not going to work. How are you going to pass the selector?

Answer (score -1):

This is the last version of my method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def exist(browser, selector, id):
    try:
        browser.find_element(By.selector, id)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

I was giving three attributes instead of just two!

Comment: You're still accessing `By.selector`, which raises the original `AttributeError`. The number of attributes (arguments) alone shouldn't fix the issue.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen You are right ... its not working ... I made like this and its working find_element(getattr(By, selector), id)